# Is it possible to jungle with every hero in the game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know a lot of the junglers can jungle but can all of the heroes do so? I see no reason they wouldn't be able to but i am not 100% sure if its possible or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes you can. Even with the "squishest" champion, let's say "Sona"

or Karthus

But it's not worth with EVERY champion.

The best jungler are:

- Clear his jungle FAST.
- Gank in every opportunity
- Do not wait level 6 or more for ganks (at level 2~4 you usually can
  gank with normal junglers)

> So, if you are looking for some for fun jungle, go ahead, pick
>   "random" and a smite and go for it (**of course, runes and mastery are
>   the most important thing here**). But if you are trying to play hi
>   elo, go for the default jungler.

Answer (score 5):

Its possible but its definitely not recommended. Runes are required to determine the speed of a jungler as well as its survivability before being forced to go back to the fountain to heal.

Answer (score 0):

With the new jungle it is possible to jungle with every hero, some just faster then others. Try check out saintvicious stream, he have almost jungled with every possible hero in LoL.

Answer (score 0):

Every hero technically can, but that doesn't mean they are an effective jungler. Most jungles have certain aspects to their character that make them effective. Shyvana is a speedy jungler, which makes her great for counter jungling. Heroes like skarner and ram us have disables.

An example of a not very effective jungler would be sona. She is an amazing support, but would have a harder time finding a  place in the jungle. She wouldn't be able to gank until level 6, and even then she wouldn't do as much during the gank compared to other junglers, besides her ultimate, really. Plus she would fall behind in the jungle, because she cannot clear the camps fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

many champions are not effective as a jungler because they are either kill too slowly, so takes too long to clear the jungle, or are too squishy and have to back too often to heal, to keep up in jungling as the more common junglers. For example a kennen could definitely kill any camps even at level one, but he will kill them very slowly, and he is so squishy that he can barely go over one full clear with armor 5 pot start and burning all 5 pots. 
so all champions can jungle, but some are so ineffective that it would not be considered as a viable jungler.

Answer (score -2):

No, there are many champions who are very squishy at the beginning of games. It would be near impossible for say..Sona.

Comment: -1 let's say ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu0DtgKdtt0

Comment: Oh wow. That's..amazing.